# Hide unused image in ScrollView (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, io, scrollview

I need to hide the unused image. How to do it?
In my code I have three images, but not always all of the images are being  used. How can I hide the third image? And later if I add the third image I need to unhide this image again without code changes.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase
import SDWebImage

class ScrollViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

var image = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loadImages()

}
func loadImages() {

    Database.database().reference().child("Студии2").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        let newImages = [String]()

        for child in snapshot.children {
            let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
            let imageSnap = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "Photo")
            let dict = imageSnap.value as! [String: AnyObject]
            let url = dict["image"] as? String ?? ""
            let url2 = dict["image1"] as? String ?? ""
            let url3 = dict["image3"] as? String ?? ""
            self.image.append(url)
            self.image.append(url2)
            self.image.append(url3)

            for i in 0..<self.image.count {
                let imagesArray = UIImageView()
                imagesArray.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: self.image[i]))
                let xPos = self.view.frame.width * CGFloat(i)
                imagesArray.frame = CGRect(x: xPos, y: 0, width: self.scrollView.frame.width, height: self.scrollView.frame.height)


                self.scrollView.contentSize.width = self.scrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(i + 1)
                self.scrollView.addSubview(imagesArray)
            }
        }
        self.image = newImages
    })
}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: You need to be more specific on *unused images*, *third image*, *hide images* and probably need a translator. unused in what sense?, hide from where?, what is third image?.... This is a very vague question...

Comment: If you check my code, i received in scrollView ["image3"]... My firebase database don't have string "image3". And when run app in simulator i see in my scrollView  two images and one empty image (because his not present). So me need hide one empty image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the empty objects out so the content size will be correct

here is how to do it

```
func loadImages() {
   Database.database().reference().child("Студии2").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

      for child in snapshot.children {
         guard let snap = child as? DataSnapshot else { return }
         let imageSnap = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "Photo")
         guard let dict = imageSnap.value as? [String: AnyObject] else { return }

         self.image.append(dict["image"] as? String ?? "")
         self.image.append(dict["image1"] as? String ?? "")
         self.image.append(dict["image3"] as? String ?? "")

         let links = self.image.filter { !$0.isEmpty }

         let size = self.view.frame.size

         links.enumerated().forEach {
            let imageView = UIImageView()
            imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: $0.element))
            let x = size.width * CGFloat($0.offset)
            imageView.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)

            self.scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
         }

         self.scrollView.contentSize.width = size.width * CGFloat(links.count)
      }
      self.image = [String]()
   })
}
```

Comment: When a changed my code and launched app i received empty screen without images. If i right understand i had to change everything except this code? 
Database.database().reference().child("Студии2").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
let newImages = [String]()
for child in snapshot.children {
let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
let imageSnap = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "Photo")
let dict = imageSnap.value as! [String: AnyObject]
let url = dict["image"] as? String ?? ""
...
let url3 = dict["image3"] as? String ?? ""
self.image.append(url)
...
self.image.append(url3)

Comment: That should be correct can you set a breakpoint on let size and see if it’s a the problem

Comment: Maybe I do not understand something, but links have no values if i set a breakpoint on let size

Comment: @ДмитрийДеникаев ok just not to confuse you I edited my answer so it will be easier for you